# use simple for loop in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, for-loop, eloquent

I just wanted to use simple for loop in my blade file to create a demo.

the example code in PHP is :

```
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
 // the loop events
}
```

the thing is I don't have any parameter to use foreach, therefore i have to use for loop.

Comment: Okay. So what is your question?

Comment: Whats your problem?? Do you use normal `for loop` in your blade view??

Comment: Hii!!, i know you are a beginner and are learning and I hope you continue to learn, for the laravel framework you can see the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops) about your problem, topics like very basic i guess if you search for the same keywords on google it will direct you to the documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple as you want

```
@for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
    {{$i}}
@endfor
```